# development and deployment on sql express. How to manage security?

Tags: .net, security, iis, sql-server-express

Is it secure to work with sql express in production?
Should I create a dedicated application pool and grant read / write permission to the user created by this pool on App_Data folder?

Comment: Yes of course its secure.  You should use the same security model you would use if you were communicating with a remote MSSQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Express can easily be made secure for professional application development.  Unlike full SQL Server which is 'secure by default', securing SQL Express really only requires a couple of things:
1) Figure out an appropriate authorization scheme for your authentication type (i.e. SQL or Windows security).
2) If you are using Windows authentication, then create the users and groups in AD first, and then create roles in SQL Express which map to the Windows groups.
3) If you are using SQL authentication,  create or use a build-in database group and add database users to that group

Regarding the IIS App_Pool process account, it is a best practice to use a dedicated (Windows user) process account for IIS, just as you should set up SQL Server with a dedicated process account.

Here's a pretty good [resource](http://www.greensql.com/content/sql-server-security-best-practices) for SQL Server security practices.